# abort-controller error in expo react native app when running it via --web mode

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to run app via web:

```
npx expo start --web
```

But I am getting error in console:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/abort-controller/polyfill.mjs:2
Module not found: Can't resolve './dist/abort-controller'
Did you mean 'abort-controller.mjs'?
BREAKING CHANGE: The request './dist/abort-controller' failed to resolve only because it was resolved as fully specified
(probably because the origin is strict EcmaScript Module, e. g. a module with javascript mimetype, a '*.mjs' file, or a '*.js' file where the package.json contains '"type": "module"').
The extension in the request is mandatory for it to be fully specified.
```

Any idea what should I do in order to run app via web? [App.js](https://github.com/knagode/react_native_expo_app_with_rails_backened/blob/main/react_native_app/App.js)